# how to fix my missing error/debug tab/window in pine script

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

my debugging tab in pine script is missing, how to find it?
it is the tab at the buttom which show you errors when you try to compile your code.
[this tab here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvtQs.jpg)

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem? My console tab disappeared and have not been able to find how to show it again...

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + `
Or right mouse button on the bottom of the pine script editor[image]